# Coordinate transformation/reprojection using DotSpatial?

Tags: c#, coordinate-system, dotspatial

The following piece of code worked with an older version of DotSpatial.

```
public static Geometry Project_EPSG25832_To_EPSG3857(byte[] wkb, int SRID)
    {
        NetTopologySuite.IO.WKBReader reader = new NetTopologySuite.IO.WKBReader();
        Geometry geom = (Geometry)reader.Read(wkb);

        var epsg25832 = new DotSpatial.Projections.ProjectionInfo();
        var epsg3857 = new DotSpatial.Projections.ProjectionInfo();
        epsg25832.ParseEsriString(ESRI_EPSG_25832);
        epsg3857.ParseEsriString(ESRI_EPSG_3857);

        Geometry transformedGeom = (Geometry)DotSpatial.Projections.GeometryTransform.TransformGeometry(geom, epsg25832, epsg3857, NetTopologySuite.NtsGeometryServices.Instance.CreateGeometryFactory());

        return transformedGeom;
    }
```

I had to upgrade the DotSpatial suite to the latest version and now the above code breaks. It seems the "DotSpatial.Projections.GeometryTransform" class doesn't exist any more.

I can't seem to find anything similar in the new version of DotSpatial except for this method

```
Reproject.ReprojectPoints(xy, z, pStart, pEnd, 0, 1);
```

...but it takes an array of points...

Anybody know of a nice and easy way of coming from a WKB to an array of points, or maybe there is another library that is easier to use in .NET/C#??

Comment: You mix `DotSpatial` and `NetTopologySuite`. Is this by intention?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the code I ended up using:

```
public static Geometry Project_EPSG25832_To_EPSG3857(byte[] wkb)
        {
            NetTopologySuite.IO.WKBReader reader = new NetTopologySuite.IO.WKBReader();
            Geometry geom = (Geometry)reader.Read(wkb);

            double[] pointArray = new double[geom.Coordinates.Count() * 2];
            double[] zArray = new double[1];
            zArray[0] = 1;

            int counterX = 0;
            int counterY = 1;
            foreach (var coordinate in geom.Coordinates)
            {
                pointArray[counterX] = coordinate.X;
                pointArray[counterY] = coordinate.Y;

                counterX = counterX + 2;
                counterY = counterY + 2;
            }

            var epsg25832 = new DotSpatial.Projections.ProjectionInfo();
            var epsg3857 = new DotSpatial.Projections.ProjectionInfo();
            epsg25832.ParseEsriString(ESRI_EPSG_25832);
            epsg3857.ParseEsriString(ESRI_EPSG_3857);

            DotSpatial.Projections.Reproject.ReprojectPoints(pointArray, zArray, epsg25832, epsg3857, 0, (pointArray.Length / 2));

            counterX = 0;
            counterY = 1;
            foreach (var coordinate in geom.Coordinates)
            {
                coordinate.X = pointArray[counterX];
                coordinate.Y = pointArray[counterY];

                counterX = counterX + 2;
                counterY = counterY + 2;
            }
            **geom.GeometryChanged();**
            return geom;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Where is the problem, simply use this:

```
double lat = 8.654;
double lon = 38.123;

double[] xy = new double[2] { lat, lon };
double[] z = new double[1] { 1234.5 };

Reproject.ReprojectPoints(xy, z, pStart, pEnd, 0, 1);

Console.WriteLine(String.Foramt("New Lat/Lon = {0}/{1}", xy[0], xy[1]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [Proj4](https://trac.osgeo.org/proj/) library. I think the number of supported projections is bigger than in all others. As far as I know the supported number of projections in NetTopologySuite is very limited.

There is a wrapper available in order to use Proj4 in C#: http://ftp.dfg.ca.gov/Public/BDB/Tools/proj4/