# How to make a point from real latitude and longitude values

Tags: c#, spherical-geometry, mercator, sharpmap

My program has a center point and one moving object . At this moment this point is somewhere in Europe.But Now i have to change that point from the latitude and longitude values(of Australia) . Please see [This program](https://github.com/jorik041/sharpmap/blob/master/Examples/WinFormSamples/FormMovingObjectOverTileLayer.cs)  . from that program i could make program running .

CODE PART`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using GeoAPI.Geometries;
using NetTopologySuite.Geometries;
using SharpMap.Layers;
using SharpMap.Data;
using SharpMap.Styles;
using SharpMap.Rendering.Thematics;
using BruTile.Web;
using WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties;

#if DotSpatialProjections
using GeometryTransform = DotSpatial.Projections.GeometryTransform;
#else
using GeometryTransform = GeoAPI.CoordinateSystems.Transformations.GeometryTransform;
#endif

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class FormMovingObjectOverTileLayer : Form
    {

        private List<IGeometry> geos = new List<IGeometry>();

        private bool movingUp = true;
        private bool movingLeft = true;
        GeoAPI.Geometries.Coordinate position;

        public FormMovingObjectOverTileLayer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
            this.UpdateStyles();
        }

        private void FormMovingObjectOverTileLayer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //Lisbon...
#if DotSpatialProjections
            var mathTransform = LayerTools.Wgs84toGoogleMercator;
            var geom = GeometryTransform.TransformBox(
                new Envelope(-9.205626, -9.123736, 38.690993, 38.740837),
                mathTransform.Source, mathTransform.Target);
#else



            var mathTransform = LayerTools.Wgs84toGoogleMercator.MathTransform;
            GeoAPI.Geometries.Envelope geom = GeometryTransform.TransformBox(
                new Envelope(-9.205626, -9.123736, 38.690993, 38.740837), mathTransform);

#endif


            //Google Background
            TileAsyncLayer layer2 = new TileAsyncLayer(new OsmTileSource(), "TileLayer - OSM");


            this.mapBox1.Map.BackgroundLayer.Add(layer2);
            var gf = new GeometryFactory(new PrecisionModel(), 3857);

            //Adds a static layer
            var staticLayer = new VectorLayer("Fixed Marker");
            //position = geom.GetCentroid();
            var aux = new List<IGeometry>();
            aux.Add(gf.CreatePoint(geom.Centre));


            staticLayer.Style.Symbol = Resources.PumpSmall;
            var geoProviderFixed = new SharpMap.Data.Providers.GeometryProvider(aux);
            staticLayer.DataSource = geoProviderFixed;
            this.mapBox1.Map.Layers.Add(staticLayer);


            //Adds a moving variable layer
            VectorLayer pushPinLayer = new VectorLayer("PushPins");
            position = geom.Centre;

            geos.Add(gf.CreatePoint(position));
            pushPinLayer.Style.Symbol = Resources.ZoomToExtents1;

            var geoProvider = new SharpMap.Data.Providers.GeometryProvider(geos);
            pushPinLayer.DataSource = geoProvider;
            this.mapBox1.Map.VariableLayers.Add(pushPinLayer);

            this.mapBox1.Map.ZoomToBox(geom);
            this.mapBox1.Refresh();

        }
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double dx, dy;
            if (movingLeft)
                dx = -100;
            else
                dx = 100;

            if (movingUp)
                dy = 100;
            else
                dy = -100;

            position.X = position.X + dx;
            position.Y = position.Y + dy;

            if (position.X < this.mapBox1.Map.Envelope.MinX)
                movingLeft = false;
            else if (position.X > this.mapBox1.Map.Envelope.MaxX)
                movingLeft = true;

            if (position.Y < this.mapBox1.Map.Envelope.MinY)
                movingUp = true;
            else if (position.Y > this.mapBox1.Map.Envelope.MaxY)
                movingUp = false;

            VariableLayerCollection.TouchTimer();
            //this.mapBox1.Refresh();

        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.timer1.Enabled = false;
        }


        private void Form2_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.mapBox1.Refresh();
        }

        private void FormMovingObjectOverTileLayer_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            this.timer1.Stop();
        }

    }
}
`
```

Comment: That's a lot of code to read through. Are you getting specific error messages? Is there a particular problem in this code that needs addressing? The first thing I notice is Envelope(-9.205626, -9.123736, 38.690993, 38.740837) is not in Australia... apart from that WGS84 Web Mercator is worldwide. http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/7483/

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Thank Michael. There is no error the problem is how to convert latitude an longitude values to this format

Comment: It should be the same. A coordinate from the GPS will probably be in WGS84/DD  and you're transforming into Web Mercator, which works the same way in Europe, Asia, U.S... everywhere. North and South Poles might be a little distorted though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using DotSpatial.

Here's a similar question and answer: [Coordinate transformation/reprojection using DotSpatial](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127374/coordinate-transformation-reprojection-using-dotspatial)

This looks like the documentation for the library: http://www.mapwindow.org/downloads/documentation/dotspatial-1.0/html/66de9da3-2eda-7ca5-9ee5-e9b8a76f8392.htm